# Problem connecting to Webmin

Tags: webmin

I have installed Webmin with the view to try an understand what is all running.

Yesterday I had it setup with login and password, but today when I try to get access to the server with:
https://ubuntu:10000/ in order to login, I get unable to connect, the page does not load. Seems like there is no connection.

- I tried `http://localhost:10000` and `https://localhost:10000` They both returned the same unable to connect response.

I am not sure of what it means to turn https on. ... the https and http is not showing.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you did not setup `webmin` with https you need to to connect using http://localhost:10000 instead of https://localhost:10000.

If `webmin` is not starting by default on your computer you need to create a script in your `/etc/init.d` with this content, call the script *webmin*

```
#!/bin/sh
# chkconfig: 235 99 10
# description: Start or stop the Webmin server
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: webmin
# Required-Start: $network $syslog
# Required-Stop: $network
# Default-Start: 2 3 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Description: Start or stop the Webmin server
### END INIT INFO

start=/etc/webmin/start
stop=/etc/webmin/stop
lockfile=/var/lock/subsys/webmin
confFile=/etc/webmin/miniserv.conf
pidFile=/var/webmin/miniserv.pid
name='Webmin'

case "$1" in
'start')
    $start >/dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null
    RETVAL=$?
    if [ "$RETVAL" = "0" ]; then
        touch $lockfile >/dev/null 2>&1
    fi
    ;;
'stop')
    $stop
    RETVAL=$?
    if [ "$RETVAL" = "0" ]; then
        rm -f $lockfile
    fi
    pidfile=`grep "^pidfile=" $confFile | sed -e 's/pidfile=//g'`
    if [ "$pidfile" = "" ]; then
        pidfile=$pidFile
    fi
    rm -f $pidfile
    ;;
'status')
    pidfile=`grep "^pidfile=" $confFile | sed -e 's/pidfile=//g'`
    if [ "$pidfile" = "" ]; then
        pidfile=$pidFile
    fi
    if [ -s $pidfile ]; then
        pid=`cat $pidfile`
        kill -0 $pid >/dev/null 2>&1
        if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then
            echo "$name (pid $pid) is running"
            RETVAL=0
        else
            echo "$name is stopped"
            RETVAL=1
        fi
    else
        echo "$name is stopped"
        RETVAL=1
    fi
    ;;
'restart')
    $stop ; $start
    RETVAL=$?
    ;;
*)
    echo "Usage: $0 { start | stop | restart }"
    RETVAL=1
    ;;
esac
exit $RETVAL
```

make this executable with `sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/webmin` and add it to the startup procedure with `update-rc.d webmin defaults`. After this `webmin` will start with your computer.

To avoid all these small things you can also download `webmin` as a debian package that you can install in your system.

Fist you need to remove the current `webmin` tar install

```
/etc/webmin/uninstall.sh
```

Then install all `webmin` dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install perl libnet-ssleay-perl openssl libauthen-pam-perl libpam-runtime libio-pty-perl apt-show-versions python
```

Download the latest deb file from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webadmin/files/) or use this command to download the current latest version (up to this date)

```
wget http://dfn.dl.sourceforge.net/project/webadmin/webmin/1.570/webmin_1.570_all.deb
```

After downloading the file you can install it with

```
sudo dpkg -i webmin_1.570_all.deb
```

`webmin` will install, configure all necessary scripts and be ready for you in https://localhost:10000 all the time so you can login with your username / password.

Comment: I just tried it and it returned the same result, namely: Unable to connect. ... thanks.

Comment: I tried 'https://localhost:10000' and 'http://locahost:10000' and they both returned the same unable to connect response. I am not sure of what it means to turn https on. ... the https and http is not showing. ... thanks.

Comment: I downloaded the tar from www.webmin.com and followed the installation instructions ... it all worked yesterday:) .... thanks

Comment: I just found a way ... not sure if it is the correct way, but here goes ... sudo /etc/webmin/start .... then one logs onto the server with https://localhost:10000, and walla I'm in webmin.... thanks .... edit .... the https is not showing but that should precede the //localhost:10000

Comment: updated answer to reflect your comments. tested on a running system so hope there are not typos around ;) have fun and gl.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, but nonetheless I had a similar problem and my solution was to ensure port 10000 was accepting connection. So if you are having a similar problem, you may want to try this. Connect to your server through SSH and execute the following command:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 0/0 -s 0/0 --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT
```

For me it worked instantly. Good luck.

**Edit:**

Forgot to mention, you should save your iptables after adding your new rule, this can be done by running `sudo service iptables save` on your command line. Otherwise on server reboot, any changes done in your iptables will be lost. If that doesn't work, you can try `sudo /sbin/service iptables save`.

Comment: For me, a bit different rule did the trick: `sudo iptables -A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: However, it got lost after server restart. So, actually, the solution was, at first, to manually add the rule above, then log in to Webmin, go to "Un-used Modules" -> "FirefallD", make sure "Show rules in zone: public" is selected, click on "Add allowed port" ("Webmin" itself is not defined in the services to add it as a service), enter "10000" as the port, create and then "Apply configuration".

Comment: Good, yes, you have to save it by running `sudo iptables save` otherwise on reboot it will not add the rule. Adding this to my answer. Glad you got it working.

Comment: Another thing: if I install Webmin using Virtualmin's setup script, the additional FirewallD rule (along with many others) are added for me, thus another solution: install Webmin by installing Virtualmin. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the `port` and `listen` in \etc\webmin\miniserv.conf

example:

```
port=1000
listen=1000
```

Then restart webmin:

```
/etc/init.d/webmin restart
```

Now use:

```
https://iporhost:1000/
```

Answer (score 0):

mine did this same exact thing after a reboot and i was able to access it by using the domain name of my modem/router  (ex. https://myservername.routername.com:10000)

Comment: @maythux "*and i was able to access it using the domain name of my modem/router*" So you see, this *is* an answer, and **not** a "me too" post. It just looks like a "me too" post for the first few words.